# Plasmoid - connect KDE signal with QML UI

Tags: kde, qt, plasma

I'm working on this small KDE plasmoid and I really like the QtQuick/QML, but now I have this requirement.
I need to do an action when a window is shown or closed in KDE.
KDE API have signals for that: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/Scripting/API_4.9#Signals_3

```
windowClosed(KWin::Toplevel *toplevel, KWin::Deleted *deleted)
windowShown(KWin::Toplevel *toplevel)
```

But, I don't know how to connect the KDE signals with my QML plasmoid.

I guess with a little bit of C++ it might be possible.
No problem with mixing C++ and QML, this is documented by Qt quite good.

I think what I need is C++ code, which takes the qml as a layout and setup the signal connection.

Is that even possible?

Comment: I have at least small progress now.
I'm able to create a basic plasmoid with Python and PyKDE and use [DeclarativeWidget](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.7-api/plasma/Plasma.DeclarativeWidget.html) which is able to load a qml file.

Comment: I have almost working example now, I'll provide a link to the code here soon.